# content type not overriding in drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I created a content type called custom content type..now I want to override the content type with the form id.I included bartik_theme in template.php and custom-content-type-node-form as my form id and I created custom-content-type-node-form.tpl.php in template in bartik..but am unable to override.I try to use dpm() function to print array structure that also not working.thank you in advance..

```
       I included this in template.php

         function bartik_theme() {
         return array(
          'custom_content_type_node_form' => array(
           'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
           'template' => 'templates/custom-content-type-node-form',
           'render element' => 'form'
            ),
            );
            }

        I created  custom-content-type-node-form.tpl.php in template folder

           <?php
               dpm($form);

                  hide($form['body']);

                 print drupal_render_children($form['field_custom_image']);
                   print drupal_render_children($form['title']);

                     print drupal_render_children($form);
                    ?>
```

Comment: Please take a look at drupal suggestions. You may not need to implement the hook_theme at all https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your custom theme implementation is not in the theme hook suggestions array. 
Use "template_preprocess_page" hook to add a suggestion to the the hook suggestions array :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 //your checks here ...
 $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'custom_content_type_node_form';
 //...
}
```

However if you want to change form element I suggest to use "hook_form_alter" or "hook_form_FORM_ID_alter" hook.